# Iterating through lists of list in java

Tags: java, generics, nested-loops

I have two tables `User` and `Roles` with one-to-one relation as below.

```
User
_________________________________________
| Id  | user_name | full_name | creator |
_________________________________________
| 1   | a         | A         | a       |
| 2   | b         | B         | a       |
| 3   | c         | C         | a       |
| 4   | d         | D         | c       |
| 5   | e         | E         | c       |
| 6   | f         | F         | e       |
| 7   | g         | G         | e       |
| 8   | h         | H         | e       |
| 9   | i         | I         | e       |
|10   | j         | J         | i       |
_________________________________________

Roles
_______________________________________
| id | user_mgmt | others | user_id |
_______________________________________
| 1  | 1        | 1      | 1           |
| 2  | 0        | 1      | 2           |
| 3  | 1        | 0      | 3           |
| 4  | 0        | 1      | 4           |
| 5  | 1        | 1      | 5           |
| 6  | 0        | 1      | 6           |
| 7  | 0        | 0      | 7           |
| 8  | 0        | 0      | 8           |
| 9  | 1        | 0      | 9           |
________________________________________
```

The `Roles` table have `boolean` columns, so if an `User` have `user_mgmt` role he can add many users (How many users can be added by an user is not definite). I want to fetch all users created by an user and his child users ( a is parent, c is child of a and e is child of c ..) .

Here is my code to fetch users

```
public void loadUsers(){
  List<Users> users = new ArrayList<>();

  String creator = user.getUserName();
  List<Users> createdUsers = userService.getUsersByCreator(creator);
  for(Users user : createdUsers) {
    Roles role = createdUsers.getRoles();
    if(role.isEmpMgnt()){
      users.add(user);
      loadUsers();
    }
  }
}
```

This gives me an stack overflow error. If i don't call `loadUsers()` recursively it returns only a single child result. So is there any solutions to this ? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You are reinitializing users array for every call. List will always be empty anyway. You need to check if user is creator first and then call getUsersByCreator method, not inside the for loop. Code needs tidying up, this design looks so open to memory leak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you stack overflow error because `a` has creator `a`. So you have infinite loop for user a. For `a` you should set creator to `null` or skip self references in code. 
Also you should pass current user into `loadUsers()` method and read only users that are created by it. Like

```
public void loadUsers(String creator)
```

and only process users created by that creator. Here

```
String creator = user.getUserName();
```

what is user? You should use creator. Question is how do you obtain initial creator. Probably initial creator should be user where creator is null.

Comment: Nope i changed the creator of a to z but still getting same error.